# Find elements in DOM where text contains only the the characters in a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a 5x5 grid that contains random alphabetical characters. Each cell in that grid is associated with its column and row number (like so: the cell in the first row and second column would have a value of 12).
How the project works is:

- From the current time I collect the seconds;
- Then find the cells that have the same numbers as their values (like so: if the seconds are 24, I need to find the cells that have the values '24' and '42');
- After that, I need to get the number of cells that have the same letters associated with those numbers;

---

> Grid.js

---

```
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

const getRandomLetterRow = (size) =>
  Array.from({ length: size }, () => {
    return alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
  });

const generateGrid = (size = 5) => {

  return Array.from({ length: size }, () => {
    return getRandomLetterRow(size);
  });
};

function Grid() {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState(generateGrid);
  return (
    <div className="grid">
      {grid.map((row, rowIndex) => (
        <div key={rowIndex} className="table_row" value={rowIndex}>
          <div key={rowIndex}>{rowIndex}</div>
          {row.map((col, colIndex) => (
            <div key={colIndex} className="cell">
              {col}
              <p>
                {colIndex}
                {rowIndex}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

> App.js

---

```
const d = new Date();
  const s = d.getSeconds();
  function handleClick() {

  }
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <Grid/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need to find a way to find the cells have the same numbers as their values and the number of cells with same letters associated with those numbers on click.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: sorry. forgot to add the problem.
"I need to find a way to find the cells have the same numbers as their values and the number of cells with same letters associated with those numbers."

Comment: You have an array with all of your values in it.  Make your button a child of the Grid component.  Now you can just iterate over the array to return the values from it.